# Shorter try except block for many vars

Tags: python, syntax, try-catch

I am parsing some content out of different urls. Not all the urls have the same structure and thus the code fails for some urls, so the code I came up with is this (simplified version):

```
    meta_dict = {}
    try:
        meta_dict['date_published'] = html.find('date'}).text
    except:
        meta_dict['date_published'] = ''
    try:
        meta_dict['headline'] = html.find('headline').text
    except:
        meta_dict['headline']
    try:
        meta_dict['description'] = html.find('description').text
    except:
        meta_dict['description']

    return meta_dict
```

This being a simplified block, but the idea is to try and get more than 50 variables and doing a `try` `except` block for every one of them just feels too repetitive and ugly in the code too.

I know I could make a function for it and return `''` if it fails, but I want to know if there is another way to handle this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = [('date_published', 'date'), ('headline', 'headline'), ('description', 'description')]
for dict_val, html_val in l:
    try:
        meta_dict[dict_val] = html.find(html_val).text
    except:
        meta_dict[dict_val] = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list of these variables you are checking is constant, you can put them into a list and then just iterate over that list.

```
vars = [date_publis, hedheadline, description, . . . ]

for var in vars:
    try:
        meta_dict[var] = html.find(var}).text
    except:
        meta_dict[var] = ''
```

Comment: I assumed that the values in the dictionary and the values you are looking in your html are similar. If they are not, Alex answer will be more accurate. The idea is similar.